# Equivalence of $\gamma_1(t) = z_0 + R e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\gamma_2(t) = z_0 + R e^{it}, t \in [\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $R>0$,
$$\gamma_1(t) = z_0 + R e^{it}, \quad t \in [0,2\pi]$$
$$\gamma_2(t) = z_0 + R e^{it}, \quad t \in [\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}].$$
How can I prove that they are not equivalent, that is there is no $\phi: [0,2\pi] \to [\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}] $ such that $\phi$ is $C^{1}$, $\phi$ is bijective, $\phi^{-1}$ is $C^{1}$, $\phi$ is increasing, and $\gamma_2 \circ \phi = \gamma_1?$

Answer (score 0):

You did not clearly state what you mean by "equivalent". The two curves are clearly not the "same" since $\gamma_1$ begins and ends at $z_0+R$, while $\gamma_2$ begins and ends at $z_0+iR$. If you mean by "equivalent"  the existence of an increasing parameter transformation $\phi$ such that $\gamma_2\circ\phi=\gamma_1$ then the two curves are **not** equivalent, because equivalence leaves the initial and end points of a curve unchanged.

On the other hand, the two curves are equal as $1$-chains, i.e., "equivalent" if it comes to line integrals, because there are two circular arcs $\alpha$, $\beta$ such that $\gamma_1=\alpha+\beta=\gamma_2$ in the sense of addition of chains.

Comment: In this context by equivalent I mean there exists $\phi: [0,2\pi] \to [\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}] $ such that $\phi$ is $C^{1}$, $\phi$ is bijective, $\phi^{-1}$ is $C^{1}$, $\phi$ is increasing, and $\gamma_2 \circ \phi = \gamma_1.$

Comment: @Christian Blatter Thanks for the correction. I posted a new answer. I think that the new one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the contrary, i.e. there exists such a $φ$. In this case we will reach a contradiction.

If $γ_2φ=γ_1$, then for a certain $t$ we have:

$$γ_2φ(t)=γ_1(t)\Rightarrow z_0+Re^{iφ(t)}=z_0+Re^{it}\Rightarrow\\ \exists k \in \mathbb Z : φ(t)-t=2k\pi$$

We will prove that this $k$ is the same for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Indeed, suppose there exist $t_1<t_2$ and integers $k_1<k_2$ such that:

$$g(t_1)=2k_1\pi,\ g(t_2)=2k_2\pi,$$

where $g(t)=φ(t)-t, \forall t \in [0,2\pi]$. Since $φ$ is continuous as $C^1$, we get that $g$ is also continuous. $k_1<k_2$ for the integers $k_1,k_2$ implies that:

$$k_1+1\leq k_2\Rightarrow 2k_1+2\leq 2k_2\Rightarrow n\pi \in (2k_1\pi, 2k_2\pi),$$

where $n:=2k_1+1$.

We apply the Intermediate Value Theorem and so $\exists t_0\in (0,2\pi):g(t_0)=n\pi \Rightarrow φ(t_0)=t_0+n\pi$.

Then $γ_2φ(t_0)=z_0-Re^{it_0}\neq z_0+Re^{it_0}=γ_1(t_0)$.

Finally $φ(t)=t+2k\pi, \forall t \in [0,2\pi]$. Hence we do not have $φ([0,2\pi])\subset [\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}]$, impossible.

We are done.